# Can't Install Packages In Atom, SSL problems

Tags: windows, ssl, atom-editor

I have had this problem for a while and checked a lot of forums but most of the people just ended with **"I do not understand, good luck though"**. The error is on Atom.io and when it comes to installing packages, I get this error

> write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943F2:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert unexpected message:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 10
>   101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:

As you can see it complains about ssl, something about handshaking and alert number 10, now I don't do ssl so this is useless to me but this is the error I keep getting when I try to install. This is caused by the following steps

**1:** I use the GUI or CMD way to install a package for atom

**2:** I search a package, for example, "minimap" and when I do so I get that error from above

Now to state facts real quick, I don't have a proxy server of anything proxy (I don't think) and my internet connection is fine, I have another computer in my house and I have used Atom.io on it and it was working fine for that. I did this in apm, `set config strict-ssl false` and I am behind a firewal, also I used Atom before on this computer and it was able to install packages, but now it just gives that error. If you need any more information please ask for it in the comments.

Comment: `sslv3` This was [proven to be insecure a long time ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE). You should make sure your end is not trying to use SSLv3, because it's probably disabled on their end

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a problem with the version of NodeJS and OpenSSL used by Atom for machines using Intel Sky Lake / Apollo Lake CPUs and possibly other recent Intel platforms.

There's a lengthy discussion at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12691 , which suggests you might be able to replace some portion of the Node files, but the easiest thing to do is install the 32-bit version of Atom instead ( https://github.com/atom/settings-view/issues/924 ).

This should be acceptable for most users.